# Thought on project sourcing questions?

Tags: discussion

Lately it seems we get atleast one question a day in regards to where can i get this service or where can I find someone to do this.  Some of the questions have been allowed in the past but what are the thoughts from the community if we want these.  Personally, I think a majority of the answers would be considered spam from fly by shops that wont contribute to the community or the answers become invalid within a few years. So my question is where should we draw the line on these types of questions?

Comment: Make them wikis?

Answer (score 2):

I would agree that even if the question is well-intentioned they are **all** ultimately bait.

I say simply disallow any "where can I find someone to...." type questions. It is essentially resource gathering anyway.

Comment: I agree. Only exception for me would be more market-specific, generic questions like "Recommended methodology to look for...", as long as they are actually about graphic design, they have value and they haven't been asked before.